# Возможно ли в Java десериализовать JSON-строку без лишних телодвижений?

Tags: json, java, сериализация

Насколько я знаю, десериализация JSON проводится исключительно вручную, с помощью `JSONArray` и `JSONObject`. То есть мы должны примерно знать структуру нашего JSON, чтобы составить схему десериализации.

Например, мы создаем из строки объект `Response`, находим в нем массив, перебираем, для каждой итерации создаем новый объект и т.д.

А есть ли быстрый способ восстановить структуру оригинального объекта "одной строкой", как, например, это делалось в PHP `json_decode()`?

Comment: угу, просто приводишь к типу обьекта..

Answer (score 1):

> А есть ли быстрый способ восстановить структуру оригинального объекта "одной строкой", как, например, это делалось в PHP json_decode()?

Берем [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) и пишем одну строку:

```
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
```